# How to change the WMS Background Color in OpenLayers?

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, wms

I am using wms layer on a leaflet map but I can't change color and width of wms layers.

I have already tried using [BGCOLOR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20318) and [JavaScript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20361) without any success at all.

Is it possible to style WMS or since it is generated and sent by a server it can't be modified ?

```js
  // initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([35, 25], 5);

  var coastline_WMS = "http://default-environment.c5san2sqhm.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/countries/wms"
  
  L.tileLayer.wms(coastline_WMS, {
    //styles:''
    layers: 'countries_borders',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
   // maxZoom: 11,
   // minZoom: 3,
    //colors: '255 165 255',
    //SLD_BODY: sld,
    //width: 800,
    styles:'',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is because your background is transparent set this to false and then set the colour as a 0x colour code i.e. 0x00FFFF for aqua.

Here is a working example

```
L.tileLayer.wms(coastline_WMS, {
    //styles:''
    layers: 'countries_borders',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: false,
    BGCOLOR: '0x00FFFF',
    styles:'',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
}).addTo(map);
```